# $\cos$ not a contraction on $\mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

I know that $\cos$ is a contraction mapping on $[0, a]$ with $a<\pi/2$.

I also know that the proof of this uses the mean value theorem and it fails on $\Bbb R$.
However, this is not a proof to the fact that $\cos:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is not a contraction.

How would one prove that? Is there a counter example?

Thank you!

Comment: @elRosca : see the answer below plus take $x_1$ to be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\cos$ is defined from $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, it is not a contraction mapping, i.e there is no $L\in (0,1)$ such that $|\cos x_1-\cos x_2|\le L|x_1-x_2|$ for all $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb R$. If this is not the case, we could let $x_2\to x_1$ and get that
$$
\lim_{x_2\to x_1}\frac{|\cos x_1-\cos x_2|}{|x_1-x_2|}=|\sin x_1|\le L<1,
$$
for any $x_1\in \mathbb R$. This is a contradiction as $\sin$ function achieves $1$ in $\mathbb R$ .